# How to prepare variable content for a mail distributor in bash? (MacOS)

Tags: bash, macos, loops, variables, scripting

So let's say we have two files of type .txt.

Student.txt Contains several lines that look like this:

```
name.surname@xyz.com passwordText securityCode
```

File 2 is where our scripting takes place.

Now let's say we have some sort of E-Mail form like this:

```
from: leorge gukas <lgukas@xyz.com>
to: $studentName $studentSurname <$studentMail>

your password is $studentPassword and your confirmation code is $securityCode
```

How would a script that is able to do this look like? Keep in mind we have several students, not just one.

We're not sending the mails, we just create a new textile which contains all the emails created

Answer (score 2):

You can do this fairly easily with `awk`. You separate your input records into using the default field separator. The only challenge is splitting field-1 into `name`, `surname`. There are several ways to do that, one of the easiest and portable ways is to simply call `sub` 3 times to first remove everything except name. To get `surname` requires two calls to `sub`. The first removes everything from the `'@'` to the end and the next removes the `name` leaving the `surname`. Then it is just a matter of outputting in the form format you specify.

You can do that with:

```
awk '{
    email = name = surname = $1
    sub(/[.].*$/,"",name)
    sub(/@.*$/,"",surname)
    sub(/^.*[.]/,"",surname)
    print "from: leorge gukas <lgukas@xyz.com>\nto: " name " " surname " <" email ">\n\nyour password is " $2 " and your confirmation code is " $3
}' file
```

(to test you can simply select-copy and then middle-mouse paste into an xterm with the present working directory containing the `file` holding the original lines of `"name.surname@xyz.com passwordText securityCode"` -- change `file` to whatever your actual filename is)

Which will process each line in `file` resulting in four lines of output:

```
from: leorge gukas <lgukas@xyz.com>
to: name surname <name.surname@xyz.com>

your password is passwordText and your confirmation code is securityCode
```

Or for example if you piped another line to show the use of different input names to the command, e.g.:

```
echo "mickey.mouse@disney.com mouseWord Pluto" | awk '{...}'
```

You would receive:

```
from: leorge gukas <lgukas@xyz.com>
to: mickey mouse <mickey.mouse@disney.com>

your password is mouseWord and your confirmation code is Pluto
```

For details on the `awk` `sub` command see [Gawk User Guide - String Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions)

Look things over and let me know if I understood your final format and whether you have any further questions.